# I am trying to install a compressed package ending in .tar.gz and I am getting an error saying that it is not in the right format,

Tags: 12.04, tar, gzip

I am new to Ubuntu and after doing some research I still can't figure what I am doing wrong. I am downloading the a package ending in `.tar.gz`,then I when I try to use:

```
tar -xvf matlab_r2011b.tar.gz
```

I get the following error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably your downloaded `matlab_r2011b.tar.gz` is bad file , if it provides md5sum ,cross-check for it from download source.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/877292/gzip-stdin-not-in-gzip-format

Answer (score 4):

Try checking the file type with the following command:

```
file matlab_r2011b.tar.gz
```

If it tells you that it is a `tar archive` rather than `gzip compressed data`, then it is possible that the file got decompressed while being downloaded (possibly due to a faulty web server configuration on the other end).  If that is the case, just rename the archive and try again:

```
mv matlab_r2011b.tar.gz matlab_r2011b.tar
tar xvf matlab_r2011b.tar
```

Comment: `tar` hasn't required the decompression options (`-z`/`-j`) for a while now; it seems to autodetect.

Comment: Fair enough.  I've cut that part from the answer.